# How can I use a model to generate a Texture image of the model dynamically. (Unity3D/C#)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

I need to know how to generate a 2D image of a 3D model(w/rotation) during game play. I am working with C# and Unity3D.
[Edited for Clarity, I hope...]

After a bit of research: It looks like what I want is RenderTexture. I should be able to create a camera and output the camera's image to the RenderTexture asset then pull the texture from the RenderTexture.

What would be the best way to do this?

My Attempt:
Using the Unity editor I have also created a background plane, ceiling plane, and spotlight 100 units below ground. My thinking is that I can make the camera/etc. active, draw the object, save the texture, delete the object, and set the camera/etc. to non-active. My concerns are with the timing of everything...

Comment: So, what is your question, exactly? Is using `RenderTexture` an optimal way to achieve this and is it widely used? Yes.

Comment: Yes, Exactly. It didn't come out that way at all did it.... *editing* ... after doing research I didn't find about generating textures, just something about making camera/monitors using RenderTexture. I wanted to ask on here because I know next to nothing about  Unity3D and I didn't wan't to get into it just to find there was an easier way or it doesn't actually work well enough for textures.

Comment: Well, it's always a good idea to check if your way of doing things is the right and/or usual way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is usually achieved using a RenderTexture. You can actually substitute the [target texture](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-targetTexture.html) of a camera for one frame, [render to several textures at once,](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.SetTargetBuffers.html) or use a special camera that you will only activate for one frame. You can find MonoBehaviour methods [`OnPostRender`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnPostRender.html), [`OnPreRender`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnPreRender.html), [`OnWillRenderObject`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnWillRenderObject.html), [`OnRenderObject`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnRenderObject.html) and [`OnRenderImage`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnRenderImage.html) useful to control the process, as well as Camera's static events [`onPreRender`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-onPreRender.html) and [`onPostRender`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-onPostRender.html).

Comment: This is incredibly helpful with the timing of everything. Is there any way to have the rendering happen in an alternate draw space (layer?) So that you can do a sub-render in your function and do this more than once per frame? How would you effectively scale this up?